# Gvim --remote to open file and focus on the newly opened file

Tags: vim, centos, gvim, csh

I got a fairly old gvim (6.3) on CentOS 4.5. There's no `--remote-tab-silent` option  yet. Instead, I use `--remote` to open file in same gvim instance. However, there's a problem that all files are opened in gvim in background. The gvim window won't pop to the front. I have to manually switch to it. Is there any way to fix this?

More detail on steps to reproduce:

1. Open Konsole
2. Open first file '`gvim --remote file1`'. For the first time open file, gvim will pop to front.
3. Switch back to Konsole and open 2nd file '`gvim --remote file2`'. The file gets opened in gvim, but gvim window won't pop to front.

Comment: Why don't you open files from GVim itself?

Answer (score 1):

Does "`gvim --remote-expr foreground()`" work to bring gVim to the front of the window stack? If this works consistently, you might set up a shell alias to invoke the `--remote` command then the `--remote-expr` command.

Comment: it didn't work. I also found this page (http://vim.1045645.n5.nabble.com/raising-gvim-window-to-front-td1169442.html), no luck either.

Comment: Then your window manager may be semi-randomly refusing to let the window raise itself. Have you tried browsing through your desktop settings for your window manager?